# MySql Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this

```
id status
1  Pass
2  Fail
3  Pass
```

How can I count total rows and rows where status is "Fail" with their id(s) by group_concat in one select query. I am trying to get output like this

```
total group_concat(id)
3     1,2,3
1     2
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to union two separate queries:

```
select status,
       count(*) as num,
       group_concat(id) as ids
from tests as status_stats
union all
select null as status,
       count(*) as num,
       group_concat(id) as ids
from tests as total_stats
```